# Format Date based on timezone/UTC offeset

Tags: javascript, luxon, datejs, formatdatetime, javascript-date

It will be very helpful to know if there is a way to format Date based on Timezone.

Ex:we give America/Los_Angeles as timezone,the output date should be formatted as MM-DD-YYYY.If we give timezone as Asia/Kolkata, It should be changed to DD-MM-YYYY.
I wanted to know if any library have any OOB method to auto format Date based on selected Timezone.

I have already tried using Locale support.Using Locale (en-US,en-GB,ja) we can format the date but none of the libraries stores which timezone uses which locale. We can use the browser locale(**navigator.language**) But This will not give desired output on locale and timezone mismatch.

```
Ex: 
    new Date(value).toLocaleString('en-US',{timeZone: "Asia/kolkata"}) // gives o/p in MM-DD-YYYY format. 
    ideally this should give O/P in DD-MM-YYYY format.
```

most of the libraries gives an OOB method to format the date but it expects an input string.

```
Ex: DateTime.fromFormat('May 25, 1982', 'MMMM dd, yyyy')

   formatInTimeZone(date, 'America/New_York', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX') 

   dayjs('2019-01-25').format('[YYYYescape] YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ[Z]')
```

i have checked below libraries:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz

I am looking for any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: sorry i didn't notice :) i've posted an answer for javascript

Comment: Couldn't a time zone relate to many locales? What locale should JavaScript pick when it has many to choose from?

Comment: HI @phiI . I understand your point . For example when we tell (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) , this has at least 10 deferent timezones like "America/Havana","America/Indiana/Petersburg","America/Indiana/Vincennes","America/Indiana/Winamac","America/Iqaluit" ...etc. But for all of them, country is same and locale is en-US.
my requirement is when we select any one of the above 10 timezones for example, Locale should be pickedup automatically .I shouldn't be hardcoding it like "en-US".

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)

Comment: Hi @KooiInc . I have checked this reference and there is no mention of getting locale based on timezone selected :( . All they are doing is passing locale string or date format separately .

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [Intl.DateTimeFormat API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat). Here is how:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 11, 20, 3, 23, 16, 738));
// Results below assume UTC timezone - your results may vary

// Specify default date formatting for language (locale)
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));
// Expected output: "12/20/2020"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date));
// Expected output: "20/12/2020"

console.log(
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, options = {
  timeZone: "America/New_York"
}).format(date));
```

You can specify more options for formatting. Look at the [documantation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat).

Comment: Hi @InspectorGadget. This is correct But here we are hardcoding the Locale . I wanted to know if there is a way automatically locale being picked up based on timezone selected .

Answer (score 0):

First: the timeZone "India/kolkata" is not valid.

I have pointed you to my [es-date-fiddler](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler) library in a comment to your question, you answered it was not useful.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but as far as I know it is not possible to infer locale values from a timeZone value. Working with ES Dates, when no locale is given, the locale of the user is used. The locale (either specified or the users' locale) determines the formatting for `toLocaleString([locale(s)])`. In other words: `locale` is not related to `timeZone`.

Let's give an example using the aforementioned library for the current date, locale `en-IN` (India) and timeZone `Asia/Kolkata`. Maybe it helps ...

See also the library's [demo](https://kooiinc.github.io/es-date-fiddler/Demo/) for a bunch of examples.

```js
const $D = window.$D;
const now = $D(new Date(), {locale: `en-IN`, timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"});
const nowHere = $D(new Date());
console.log(`now.local: ${now.local}`);
console.log(`nowHere.local: ${nowHere.local}`);
console.log(`now.format("dd-mm-yyyy h:mi:s dp"): ${
  now.format(`dd-mm-yyyy h:mi:s dp`)}`);
console.log(`now.values.resolvedLocale:`, now.values.resolvedLocale);
console.log(`nowHere.values.resolvedLocale:`, nowHere.values.resolvedLocale);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script 
  src="https://kooiinc.github.io/es-date-fiddler/Bundle/index.browser.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @KooiInc as you rightly pointed India/kolkata is not a valid zone. It is Asia/Kolkata and i have updated the question.
Thanks for the above answer . However my requirement is to find out some machanism to auto ditect Locale based on selected timezone.
In the above example , you are still hardcoding the Locale (locale: `en-IN`).when no locale is given , It picks up default locale from browser/ OS depending upon where we are running the program.This fails when default locale - timezone are deferent pair.

Comment: For example, When we select America/chigago as timezone and default Locale is en-IN, o/p dates will be in DD-MM-YYYY format which shouldnt be.As an example refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-css-javascript-basic-c3qaqn?file=index.html,style.css,index.js.  
Just an updated version of your snippet.

Comment: Hi @monk_7, I have added more clarification. Afaik it is *not* possible to infer `locale` from a given `timeZone`, at least not in ecmascript. Maybe somewhere in the depths of the world wide web some table exists where time zone labels are linked to locales.